# CSS + Different sized text areas to fit inside an image

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/adamadam123/qv2yR/

Above is the code I'm currently working with. Below is an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Its basically a chat box 'IM' and I have a blue & pink image and need to be able to get different amounts of text to sit within the image.

I also tried using the image as CSS background but found it didn't stretch to fit the text. Also tried floating and absolute positioning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thx

```
    <div class="chatMessengerBody">

        <div class="chatMessengerChatBubble chatMessengerChatBubbleBlueWrapper">
            <img src="images/chat-messenger-chat-bubble-blue.png" class="chatMessengerChatBubble chatMessengerChatBubbleBlue"/>
            <p class="chatMessengerChatBubbleContent">Great, thanks for asking. Never better to tell you the truth. So how about those dolphins?
            Great, thanks for asking. Never better to tell you the truth. So how about those dolphins?
            Great, thanks for asking. Never better to tell you the truth. So how about those dolphins?
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="chatMessengerChatBubble chatMessengerChatBubblePinkWrapper">
            <img src="images/chat-messenger-chat-bubble-pink.png" class="chatMessengerChatBubble chatMessengerChatBubblePink"/>
            <p class="chatMessengerChatBubbleContent">Great, thanks for asking. Never better to tell you the truth. So how about those dolphins?</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: instead of an image why not use a div with some padding, background color and a border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qv2yR/10/

CSS

```
.blue {
    background: #EBF7FF;
    border: 1px solid #D4F1FD;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color :#6B95B0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;    
    width: 200px;
}

.pink {
    background: #FFF8F2;
    border: 1px solid #FFEEE4;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color :#D386A8;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;    
    width: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="blue">
 this is the blue one
</div>

<div class="pink">
    this is the pink one.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an image, why not use some CSS & CSS3 rounded corners:

```
.chatMessengerChatBubblePinkWrapper {
    background:#fff8f2;
    border:1px solid #ffeadb;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```